# Criei uma navbar com um form ao lado mas quando adiciono varios inputs no form a pagina perde o background

Tags: html, css, laravel

[image: ``]

**view do form:**

```
    <div class ="registerUser">
        <h1 class="w3-xxlarge ">Cadastro de clientes</h1>
        <hr style="width: 80%">
             <form method="POST" action="">
                <h3 class="w3-xlarge leftTitle escuro">Dados do cliente:</h3><br><br>    
                    <div class ="form-group esquerda" >
                        <label>Nome:</label>
                        <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Insira o nome" required>
                        <br>
                        <label>Data de Vencimento:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="date" type="date">
                    </div>
                        <br><br> 
                <h3 class="w3-xlarge leftTitle escuro">Dados do carro:</h3><br><br> 
                    <div class ="form-group esquerda">
                        <label>Placa</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder= "Informe a placa do veiculo"  >
                        <br>
                        <label>Cor</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Informe a cor do veiculo" >
                        <br>
                        <label>Marca</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Informe a Marca do veiculo"  >
                        <br>
                        <label>Modelo</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Informe o Modelo do veiculo"  >
                                                   

                    </div>
                    <br>
                <br><br><br>
            </form>   
    </div>
</div>
```

**view da nav:**

`

```
<img src="../imgs/imgPark2.png" style="width:100%; height:12vh;">
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a  href="{{route ('ShowCar')}}" ><i class="fa fa-home w3-xxlarge"></i><br>Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a  ><i class="fa fa-user w3-xxlarge"></i><br>Clientes</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="{{route('registerUser')}}">Cadastrar cliente</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ver clientes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Data de pagamento</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Remover Cliente</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a id ="closeButton "href="{{route('Home')}}" ><i  class ="fa fa-close   w3-xxlarge"></i><br>Sair</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>`
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% ;
    background-color: lightgray;
    color:lightgray; 
  }

.spot{
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 12vw;
    position: fixed!important;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    }
        ul li {
        position: relative;
        }

        li ul {
            position: absolute;
            left: 12vw;
            top: 0;
            display: none;
            
            }
            ul li a {
                display: block;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                
                font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monospace;
                
                background:black;
                font-size: x-large;
                padding: 12px;
                border: 0.5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
             }
             li:hover ul { display: block; }


             ul li a:hover{
                text-decoration:none;
                color: black;
                background: white;
             }
.registerUser{
    text-align:center;  
    position: absolute;
    top: 15vh;
    left: 30vw;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 25px 15vw 0 00px;
    border: 3px outset #fff;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
div.esquerda{
margin-left: 5vw;
    display: inline-block;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: left  
}

.leftTitle{
    
   display: inline-block;
   width: 320px;
   text-align: left  
}

.escuro{
font-weight: 600;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que se você tentar usar a propriedade [min-height](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp#:%7E:text=The%20min%2Dheight%20property%20defines,height%20property%20has%20no%20effect.) invés de 'height' no body possa resolver, pois ela vai se adaptar ao seu conteúdo máximo, caso ele ultrapasse o mínimo.

Comparação entre os dois(px será usado no exemplo mas o funcionamento é o mesmo)

```css
#box{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
</div>
```

Agora com min-height:

```css
#box{
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
</div>
```

Dependendo de como está o seu menu, quando o body crescer, ele irá ficar no topo, uma solução interessante também é usar overflow-y

```css
#box{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
  <p>Um paragrafo</p>
</div>
```

Também notei um erro no seu código:

```
.registerUser{
text-align:center;  
position: absolute;
top: 15vh;
left: 30vw;
background-color: white;
padding: 25px 15vw 0 00px;
border: 3px outset #fff;
border-radius: 0.3rem;
div.esquerda{
margin-left: 
blabla...
```

Uma classe está dentro da outra, faltou o fechamento da classe .registerUser

Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: Quanto ao espaço em branco no background, eu resolvi de outra forma, descobri que eu tinha linkado uma bilbioteca de css que tava me atrapalhando com isso, retirei ela e ficou tudo normal :)

Comment: Mas aceitei sua resposta por ter ajudado nas outras coisas que foram de grande ajuda, Valeuzão! :D

Comment: Que bom então, fico feliz em ter ajudado

Answer (score -1):

Creio que isso possa estar acontecendo devido ao:

```
.registerUser { 
  position: absolute
}
```

Dessa forma, esse elemento terá uma maior prioridade em relação aos outros elementos(estará fora do fluxo normal do documento), além de suas dimensões serem definidas pelo conteúdo interno, que no seu caso ultrapassa as dimensões do *body*, por estas estarem definidas como 100%:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
}
```

Assim sendo, creio que uma solução possível seria remover esse dimensionamento do *body* e deixar a sua classe *.registerUser* assim:

```
.registerUser { 
  position: relative
}
```

Estou aprendendo, mas espero ter ajudado.

Segue a documentação: [position - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Tambem estou desbravando um pouco das funcionalidades do CSS entao as vezes fico um pouco perdido, mas infelizmente essa nao foi a solução pq aquela parte branca ainda continua :(